# Explain the symbol $\bigvee$ in "Adventures in Stochastic Processes"

Tags: notation

[image]What does the symbol $\bigvee$ mean in statement 1.5.1.2?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have better luck soliciting useful responses if you just copy down the statement and any explanatory text here in the body of your question. I couldn't even see the text when I followed your link.

Comment: I just found this in Wikipedia: For functions A(x) and B(x), A(x) ∨ B(x) is used to mean max(A(x), B(x)). Is it possible that what the author means is this?

Comment: I think Did is right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols.  I guess, the point of all this chapter would be clearer, if you just google for "law of rare events", e.g. see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Derivation_of_Poisson_distribution_.E2.80.94_The_law_of_rare_events. Resnick's notation doesn't allow the reader to recover the meaning from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\bigvee_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}p_k(n)=\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}p_k(n)$$
$$\bigwedge_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}p_k(n)=\min_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}p_k(n)$$